# Custom C++ iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, hash-map

So I have written a custom iterator for `std::map` that allows access to just the "values" of the map and I was wondering if it is the "correct" way to implement `std::iterator` (acts identically to `std::iterator`).

Here is the implementation I have written:

```cpp
template<typename K, typename V>
class MapValueIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, V> {
public:
    MapValueIterator();

    MapValueIterator(typename std::map<K, V>::iterator iterator) : iterator(iterator) { }

    MapValueIterator(const MapValueIterator<K, V> &iterator) : iterator(iterator.iterator) { }

    MapValueIterator<K, V> &operator=(const MapValueIterator<K, V> &iterator) {
        this->iterator = iterator.iterator;
    }

    bool operator==(const MapValueIterator<K, V> &iterator) const {
        return this->iterator == iterator.iterator;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MapValueIterator<K, V> &iterator) const {
        return this->iterator != iterator.iterator;
    }

    V &operator*() const {
        return (iterator->second);
    }

    V *operator->() const {
        return &(iterator->second);
    }

    MapValueIterator<K, V> &operator++() {
        ++iterator;

        return *this;
    }

    MapValueIterator<K, V> operator++(int) {
        return (*this)++;
    }

private:
    typename std::map<K, V>::iterator iterator;
};
```

And an example of how it can be used:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> values;

values.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1));
values.insert(std::make_pair(1, 2));
values.insert(std::make_pair(2, 5));

MapValueIterator<int, int> begin(values.begin());
MapValueIterator<int, int> end(values.end());

for (auto iterator = begin; iterator != end; ++iterator) {
    printf("%d\n", *iterator);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but you could also template on the map type to be able to use it with an `unordered_map` or a `multimap`. You could arguably use a [template-template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) parameter in this case.

Comment: @glampert, I have looked into doing this, however it seems `unordered_map` and `map` have differing numbers of template parameters and all of the parameters are required when defining the template (i.e. `template<template<class, class, class, class> class M, typename K, typename V>` only works for `map` while `template<template<class, class, class, class, class> class M, typename K, typename V>` only works for `unordered_map` (note the extra class in the template).

Comment: As it turns out, I can use `template<template<class...> M, typename K, typename V>` which works perfectly!

Comment: You don't need template/template parameters. You can just use the template `M`. Then the constructor parameter is `M::iterator` and the value type can be retrieved from `M::mapped_type`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks about perfect.

You got the post increment wrong though:

```
MapValueIterator<K, V> operator++(int) {
    return (*this)++;
}
```

I believe this goes into an infinite recursion.

Thus this is normally implemented as:

```
MapValueIterator<K, V> operator++(int) {
    MapValueIterator<K, V>  result(*this);  // get a copy for return
                                            // so this can be used
                                            // unaltered in the expression

    // Now implement the current object.
    ++(*this);

    // Returned the saved copy.
    return result;
}
```

The only difference is that the `std::map<K,V>::iterator` type actually implements the `Bidirectional iterator` concept. The question is why is your iterator only implement the `Forward iterator` concept.

Answer (score 8):

I have one other addition to what Loki has already pointed out.

The C++ committee has voted to deprecate inheriting from `std::iterator` as of C++17. The current recommendation is apparently to write those `typedef`s yourself.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class MapValueIterator {
public:
    typedef V value_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef V *pointer;
    typedef V &reference;
    typedef std::ForwardIteratorTag iterator_category;

// ...
```

Feel free to read [the proposal to deprecate it](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0.html#2.1), if you care about why they're doing it (and such).

Comment: Just to clarify something for future readers. `std::iterator` is not getting deprecated, only the practice of inheriting from `std::iterator` in your custom iterator class has been deprecated.

Comment: Shouldn't one prefer `using value_type = V;` instead?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Some people prefer them, certainly. I do in some cases, but not others.